# Iterate over $PATH variable using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

If I type `echo $PATH` in the terminal I get the following result:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/fnorbert/.local/bin:/home/fnorbert/bin
```

I want to iterate over these paths using a shell script, but I do not know how to do that.
I tried the following:

```
for i in 1 2 3  
do
    echo $PATH | cut -d':' -f$i
done
```

This prints the first three paths, but I want to represent every path with the variable `i` if it is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `read` with delimiter set as `:`

```
while read -d ':' p; do
   echo "$p"
done <<< "$PATH:"
```

Comment: This seems to drop the last element of the var: `% FOO="one:two:three" ; while read -d ':' p; do echo "$p" ; done <<< "$FOO"` results in "(empty) one two"

Comment: Good point @Palpatim, I have corrected it by appending `:` in `$PATH`

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is probably to change `IFS` to a colon and let the word splitting do it:

```
IFS=:
for p in $PATH ; do 
    echo "$p"
done
```

But that might trigger file name globbing, in the weird case that your `PATH` contained characters like `*?[]`. You'd need to use `set -f` to avoid that.

Though changing `IFS` might be considered problematic anyway, since it affects the rest of the script. So in Bash, we could just split the paths to an array with `read -a`, this doesn't have a problem with glob characters either:

```
IFS=: read -a paths <<< "$PATH"
for p in "${paths[@]}" ; do
    echo "$p"
done
```

Comment: Care, playing with `$IFS`! Save and restore: use `OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=:; ... IFS="$OIFS"`

Comment: @F.Hauri, like I said, it affects the rest of the script, so you would need to do something like that. (Though at least in Bash, just unsetting `IFS` makes it act like the default value was in use.) Or you could use the latter option, since there the assignment takes only effect for the `read`.

Comment: this solution will work in instances where the source var ($PATH or whatever) has only one value and no occurance of the record separator (i.e. no colon :). So in cases where it is possible there will be only one value in the $var, you can use the same code. It is also neat and simple.

Answer (score 4):

with echo:

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

sed:

```
sed 's/:/\n/g' <<< "$PATH"
```

tr:

```
tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"
```

python:

```
python -c "import os; print os.environ['PATH'].replace(':', '\n')"
```

for iterate use for:

```
for i in ${PATH//:/ }; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Don't assume a directory name doesn't contain a newline. (You can't really assume a directory doesn't contain a colon, either, but it is at least documented that a directory name containing a colon shouldn't be used with `PATH`.)

Comment: I know, but normally no one (I hope) use newline in name, and if use, like u said they shouldn't be used with PATH.

Comment: I didn't say a directory with a newline shouldn't be used with `PATH`. I'm saying don't recommend a solution that places an unnecessary restriction on the value of `PATH`. (In an ideal world, `PATH` would be a proper array with no unnecessary restrictions to accomodate in-band delimiters; until then, we are stuck with colons.)

Comment: Avoid useless fork: `for in in ${PATH//:/ }; do` could be enough!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trivial solution, that extends your attempt a little

```
for i in $( echo "$PATH" | cut -d: -f 1- --output-delimiter=" " ) ; 
do 
   echo "$i" ; 
done
```

One trick that is used here is `-f 1-` to specify all fields instead of just one.

Another trick is to use the `--output-delimiter` option.

This solution is suffers from sensitivity to special characters in directory names.

Consider the following example

```
PATH="help me":\*:now
for i in $( echo "$PATH" | cut -d: -f 1- --output-delimiter=" " ) ; 
do 
   echo "$i" ; 
done
```

This would output

```
help
me
foo
now
```

That is,

- spaces in directory names will not be treated correctly
- special characters, such as `*` will be expanded by the shell into a list of files in the current directory (`foo` is the name of a file residing in the current directory)

But if your `PATH` does not contain anything special, this would work. Otherwise or rather in all cases take the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524309/1328439) that uses `read`.

Comment: See [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for the downvote.

Comment: @chepner thank you, I updated the post to explain the issues resulting from using the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for the requirement,

```
echo $PATH | awk -F: '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print $i}}'
```

This is well efficient in performance.